# использование mapbox

Tags: ios, objective-c

Добрый день, при подвязке карт mapbox, вылазеет такая ошибка,

[ERROR] {Map}[Style]: Failed to load [mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6]: 
Может кто-нибудь сталкивался ??

При создании использовал этот гайд - https://www.mapbox.com/guides/first-steps-ios-sdk/

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2012

Answer (score 1):

Надо сбросить настройки iOS Simulator.